# How to delete entire row for x if y appears at least once in same column?

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to run a code in which I delete the entire row for entries of "x", if "y" appears at least once in the same column of "var4". I can't find any solution in R. Below is what I tried.

In the code below, I tried to tell R that if var4 contains at least one y, all rows containing x should be filtered out/removed.

```
Example for df:

var1 var2 var3 var4
 a    b    b    a
 b    a    b    x  
 a    b    a    x
 a    a    a    y

 if (all(df$var4 %in% c("y"))) { 
 df <- filter(!var4 %in% c("x"))
 }
```

So, I would like to delete rows 2&3 because y appears in var4. Unfortunately the code above doesn't return any change in df, even though y appears several times in var4.

Many thanks. I appreciate any kind of recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, `filter` statement is not getting the data.  Instead, it can be

```
library(dplyr)
if("y" %in% df$var4) {
        df <- df %>%
                  filter(!var4 %in% "x")
  }

df
#  var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    a    b    b    a
#2    a    a    a    y
```

---

It can be also written as

```
df %>%
    filter("y" %in% var4 & !var4 %in% 'x')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c("a", "b", "a", "a"), var2 = c("b", "a", 
"b", "a"), var3 = c("b", "b", "a", "a"), var4 = c("a", "x", "x", 
"y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun . Indeed the filter did not get the data. Now it works fine.

Comment: I have a further question @akrun: How would I implement it if I would like to execute the command by group? e.g. by var3? 

     by(df, df$var3) %>%
              df %>%
          filter("y" %in% var4 & !var4 %in% 'x')      ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be `df %>% group_by(var3) %>% filter(...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base R commands.

`df[!df$var4 == "x", ]` should do it.

`df$var4 == "x"` will return a vector of TRUE/FALSE

```
> df$var4 == "x"
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The ! in front of it flips the TRUE FALSE

```
> !df$var4 == "x"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then the bracket notation refers to subsetting the object by rows, then columns.

`df[rows,columns]`

Putting it all together, the following will subset rows based on the criteria supplied, and include all columns.

```
df[!df$var4 == "x", ]
```

Note that the nothing after the `,` means include all columns.

Comment: The action `df[!df$var4 == "x", ]`  will only be done if `df$var4` contains `y` as the OP stated.

Comment: I'm not sure about scanning efficiency, but if you have to evaluate if `y` is in `df$var4`, it seems that subsetting where that is never the case will still be the same evaluation right?  However, I do stand corrected for not exactly getting the OP's point. I do also see that subsetting that is no different than not is wasted cycles.